# How can a power automate flow set custom metadata without destroying 'modified by'?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am automatically maintaining some metadata that can be used in filters. Every time a file in a document library is modified, I can get a flow to run, and it sets my metadata correctly, but the only "modified by" for the affected files (and eventually, the entire library) has become the user who owns the flow.

I see in other situations where a programmer could set the other user's name as the "Editor" before making API call, and as long as the authenticated user is a site collection administrator, that will preserve the other user's name. There doesn't seem to be any such option in power automate. Can it be done? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

By default, "modified by" filed shows the user whose connection is being used in the flow.

I don't think it's possible to change.